Android Studio cannot save files on network drive
I cannot create projects on network drives on Windows with version

Windows 10 Pro
22H2
26.‎08.‎2024
19045.3693
Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19053.1000.0


But on the other PC with this Windows version all good

Windows 10 Pro
22H2
14.‎12.‎2023
19045.3803
Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19053.1000.0

Studio creates files on this disk, but cant work with them. If i creating project on local drive and then moving on network drive - i cant save files in Studio
What should I do? I have all admin rights
I've tried to install bunch of versions Studio, nothing changed

So you have opened an Android project located on network drive U:\app in Android Studio which works but now you can not save changes? Make sure not to start Android Studio with Admin permissions via UAC dialog as processes started via UAC don't have access to your network drives (because the user account after UAC elevation is a different account and has no mounted network drives).

I open Studio on my own behalf. And this error occurs both when creating a project and when opening an existing one on any network drive

In general placing Android projects on network drives is not recommended as (if it works at all) will slow down the build process because of network latency. BTW: have you checked that you are the only one trying to open that project(s)? May be another user has opened that file(s) and thus you can not overwrite them. Better use a central Git server/repo where all users can clone the data and create a local copy.

Robert, this problem occurs not only with changing file, but also with creating on specific windows version. As you can see in topic post it works perfect on the second PC
